# Does anyone know how to implement useDropzone hook and not <Dropzone /> (component) together with react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, dropzone, react-final-form

for example 
if i have

```
const ImageInput = ({fieldPropsFromFinalForm}) => {
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, open } = useDropzone({ onDrop, accept: 'image/jpeg, image/png' });
    .
    .
    .
    return (<input {...getInputProps()} {...fieldPropsFromFinalForm} /> )

}
```

that way input doesn't work obvious but i have no idea how to make it work how to handle them together. i'm new to react and i hope that i haven't asked wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to invoke `onChange` of the `fieldPropsFromFinalForm` in the `onDrop` callback

Please find [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-stallman-lserv) sandbox for example

Please find the Code for `<ImageInput/>` Component

**ImageInput**

```
 const ImageInput = props => {
  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    // Do something with the files
    props.input.onChange(acceptedFiles);
  }, []);
  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
    onDrop,
    accept: "image/jpeg, image/png"
  });
  return (
    <div {...getRootProps()}>
      <input {...getInputProps()} {...props} />
      {isDragActive ? (
        <p>Drop the files here ...</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      )}
      {props.input.value
        ? props.input.value.map(file => {
            return <div>{file.path}</div>;
          })
        : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Sample Form**

```
function SampleForm() {
  const onSubmit = values => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        {props => (
          <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
            <Field name="myField">
              {props => (
                <div>
                  <ImageInput {...props} />
                </div>
              )}
            </Field>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        )}
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: would be possible use this inside an fieldArray in react final form? thanks